# How to get only one feasible solution using JOptimizer for a linear programming p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m that having multi or unlimited number of solutions?

Tags: java, linear-programming, joptimizer

JOptimizer is an opensource java library that help to develop most Decision Support Systems.
See: joptimizer.com/
I'm using JOptimizer to get optimum solutions for linear programming problems.
See: joptimizer.com/linearProgramming.html

I could successfully get answers for most linear programming problems using it.
Eg: minimize 3x+4y such that 2x+3y >= 8, 5x+2y >= 12, x >= 0, y >= 0 can be solved using JOptimizer as follows.

```
import com.joptimizer.functions.ConvexMultivariateRealFunction;
import com.joptimizer.functions.LinearMultivariateRealFunction;
import com.joptimizer.optimizers.JOptimizer;
import com.joptimizer.optimizers.OptimizationRequest;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

/**
 * @author K.P.L.Kanchana
 */

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Objective function (plane)
        LinearMultivariateRealFunction objectiveFunction = new LinearMultivariateRealFunction(new double[] {3.0, 4.0}, 0); //minimize 3x+4y

        //inequalities (polyhedral feasible set G.X<H )
        ConvexMultivariateRealFunction[] inequalities = new ConvexMultivariateRealFunction[4];
        // x >= 0
        inequalities[0] = new LinearMultivariateRealFunction(new double[]{-1.0, 0.00}, 0.0);  // focus: -x+0 <= 0 
        // y >= 0
        inequalities[1] = new LinearMultivariateRealFunction(new double[]{0.0, -1.00}, 0.0);  // focus: -y+0 <= 0
        // 2x+3y >= 8
        inequalities[2] = new LinearMultivariateRealFunction(new double[]{-2.0, -3.00}, 8.0); // focus: -2x-3y+8 <= 0
        // 5x+2y >= 12
        inequalities[3] = new LinearMultivariateRealFunction(new double[]{-5.0, -2.00}, 12.0);// focus: -5x-2y+12 <= 0

        //optimization problem
        OptimizationRequest or = new OptimizationRequest();
        or.setF0(objectiveFunction);
        or.setFi(inequalities);
        //or.setInitialPoint(new double[] {0.0, 0.0});//initial feasible point, not mandatory
        or.setToleranceFeas(1.E-9);
        or.setTolerance(1.E-9);

        //optimization
        JOptimizer opt = new JOptimizer();
        opt.setOptimizationRequest(or);
        int returnCode = opt.optimize();

        double[] sol = opt.getOptimizationResponse().getSolution();

        System.out.println("Length: " + sol.length);
        for (int i=0; i<sol.length/2; i++){
            System.out.println( "X" + (i+1) + ": " + Math.round(sol[i]) + "\ty" + (i+1) + ": " + Math.round(sol[i+1]) );
        }
    }

}
```

But there are some linear programming problems that having multi or unlimited number of feasible solutions. such as,  Maximize 4x+3Y Subject to 8x+6y <= 25, 3x+4y <= 15, x >= 0,y >= 0.
When I tried to solve suing JOptimizer as below, it gives an error.

```
import com.joptimizer.functions.ConvexMultivariateRealFunction;
import com.joptimizer.functions.LinearMultivariateRealFunction;
import com.joptimizer.optimizers.JOptimizer;
import com.joptimizer.optimizers.OptimizationRequest;

/**
 *
 * @author K.P.L.Kanchana
 */
public class test_4_alternateOptimum {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
//        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        // Objective function (plane)
        LinearMultivariateRealFunction objectiveFunction = new LinearMultivariateRealFunction(new double[] {-4.0, -3.0}, 0); // maximize 4x+3y

        //inequalities (polyhedral feasible set G.X<H )
        ConvexMultivariateRealFunction[] inequalities = new ConvexMultivariateRealFunction[4];
        // 8x+6y <= 25
        inequalities[0] = new LinearMultivariateRealFunction(new double[]{8.0, 6.0}, -25); // 8x+6y-25<=0
        // 3x+4y <= 15
        inequalities[1] = new LinearMultivariateRealFunction(new double[]{1.0, 4.0}, -15); // 3x+4y-15<=0
        // x >= 0
        inequalities[2] = new LinearMultivariateRealFunction(new double[]{-1.0, 0.0}, 0);
        // y >= 0
        inequalities[3] = new LinearMultivariateRealFunction(new double[]{0.0, -1.0}, 0);

        //optimization problem
        OptimizationRequest or = new OptimizationRequest();
        or.setF0(objectiveFunction);
        or.setFi(inequalities);
        //or.setInitialPoint(new double[] {0.0, 0.0});//initial feasible point, not mandatory
        or.setToleranceFeas(1.E-9);
        or.setTolerance(1.E-9);

        //optimization
        JOptimizer opt = new JOptimizer();
        opt.setOptimizationRequest(or);
        try {
            int returnCode = opt.optimize();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // get the solution
        double[] sol = opt.getOptimizationResponse().getSolution();

        // display the solution
        System.out.println("Length: " + sol.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < sol.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("answer " + (i+1) + ": " + (sol[i]));
        }
    }

}
```

I want to fix this error by getting one feasible solution among unlimited number of solutions using JOptimizer.
But I don't know how? Is there a speccial command in the JOptimizer lib? Can somebody say about it?
all required libraries, dependancies available at my google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B84k1fZRHSMdak00TjZKNXBKSFU/view?usp=sharing
Java Doc is available here: http://joptimizer.com/apidocs/index.html
Sorry if this is a strange question, and thank you to everyone who takes the time to consider it.

Comment: Sorry to break the bad news to you, but nobody here is going to download your entire project, libs, and debug it for you.

Comment: My project is not here. There is only libraries require to JOptimizer library. Most people have to waste time to search them one by one. Thats why I gatherd all together in my google drive

Comment: IF it is JOptimizer bug, you should better ask the support and maintainers.  I agree with @OldProgrammer: no debugging here, I am sorry. And in any case no chance to help unless you put your error message.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Remember that in the first working example(above) inequalities are always in the form of G.x < h, i.e. strictly less than(not less than or EQUAL), because JOptimizer implements an interior points method solver. So all the '>=' inequities in comments should be refactored as '>' sings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue with my code. To tell the truth I had some help from alberto trivellato. He is the person who develop JOptimizer as I know. I really really appreciate him for wasting his time to find the issue. As he mentioned The issue was not with multiple solutions but with the high accuracy I'm asking to the solver. it is a best practice to not ask for more precision than you really need. Also remember that inequalities are always in the form of G.x < h, i.e. strictly less than(not less htan or EQUAL), because JOptimizer implements an interior points method solver.

Corrected code:

```
import com.joptimizer.functions.ConvexMultivariateRealFunction;
import com.joptimizer.functions.LinearMultivariateRealFunction;
import com.joptimizer.optimizers.JOptimizer;
import com.joptimizer.optimizers.OptimizationRequest;

/**
 *
 * @author K.P.L.Kanchana
 */
public class test_4_alternateOptimum {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
//        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        // Objective function (plane)
        LinearMultivariateRealFunction objectiveFunction = new LinearMultivariateRealFunction(new double[] {-4.0, -3.0}, 0); // maximize 4x+3y

        //inequalities (polyhedral feasible set G.X<H )
        ConvexMultivariateRealFunction[] inequalities = new ConvexMultivariateRealFunction[4];
        // 8x+6y < 25(no equal sign)
        inequalities[0] = new LinearMultivariateRealFunction(new double[]{8.0, 6.0}, -25); // 8x+6y-25<0
        // 3x+4y < 15
        inequalities[1] = new LinearMultivariateRealFunction(new double[]{1.0, 4.0}, -15); // 3x+4y-15<0
        // x > 0
        inequalities[2] = new LinearMultivariateRealFunction(new double[]{-1.0, 0.0}, 0);
        // y > 0
        inequalities[3] = new LinearMultivariateRealFunction(new double[]{0.0, -1.0}, 0);

        //optimization problem
        OptimizationRequest or = new OptimizationRequest();
        or.setF0(objectiveFunction);
        or.setFi(inequalities);
        //or.setInitialPoint(new double[] {0.0, 0.0});//initial feasible point, not mandatory
        or.setToleranceFeas(JOptimizer.DEFAULT_FEASIBILITY_TOLERANCE / 10); // Here was the issue
        or.setTolerance(JOptimizer.DEFAULT_TOLERANCE / 10);  // Here was the issue

        //optimization
        JOptimizer opt = new JOptimizer();
        opt.setOptimizationRequest(or);
        try {
            int returnCode = opt.optimize();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // get the solution
        double[] sol = opt.getOptimizationResponse().getSolution();

        // display the solution
        System.out.println("Length: " + sol.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < sol.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("answer " + (i+1) + ": " + (sol[i]));
        }
    }

}
```